# Power Pivot Interactive Data refresh

Tags: sharepoint-2013, powerpivot

I have an Excel workbook contain powerpivot table, data source from sql server, upload it to Sharepoint site. I can enable Schedule Data Refresh and it works but here my issues:

- Data do not refresh as soon as possible, every time i check back the configure, it always leaves unchecked. (Not sure about this, because even schedule refresh takes about 7=>15 minutes to complete)
- I cannot manually Refresh the Data or Interactive refresh, get this error every time i click Refresh All Data connections or Refresh Selected connection

> External Data Refresh Fail
>
> An error occurred while working on the Data Model in the workbook.
>   Please try again.
>
> We were unable to refresh one or more data connections in this
>   workbook.  The following connections failed to refresh

Using sharepoint 2013, sql server sp1 2012, office 2012